# Deleted /dev/dm-0

Tags: delete, undelete

So...I wanted to remove a swap file located in /dev/dm-0. I accidentally deleted the entire /dev/dm-0 directory instead of the swap file.

Is there any way to reinstall it?

I've tried installing extundelete to recover it. I needed to put the name of a partition and I don't know if I have the right name there. I put /dev/sda2/ and unmounted it using fsck, then ran the command below.
Anyhow, I don't think it worked. Please help me (ELI5)! Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

```
root@server:~# sudo extundelete --restore-directory /dev/dm-0/ /dev/sda2
NOTICE: Extended attributes are not restored.
Loading filesystem metadata ... 61 groups loaded.
Loading journal descriptors ... 3459 descriptors loaded.
Failed to restore file /dev/dm-0/
Could not find correct inode number past inode 2.
Try altering the filename to one of the entries listed below.
File name                                       | Inode number | Deleted status
.                                                 2
..                                                2
lost+found                                        11
config-4.15.0-135-generic                         6146
grub                                              10241
config-5.4.0-65-generic                           6150
System.map-4.15.0-135-generic                     6145
vmlinuz-4.15.0-135-generic                        6147
initrd.img-4.15.0-135-generic                     6152
vmlinuz-5.4.0-65-generic                          6151
System.map-5.4.0-65-generic                       6148
initrd.img-5.4.0-65-generic.new                   6153           Deleted
initrd.img-5.4.0-65-generic                       6153
initrd.img-5.4.0-65-generic.dpkg-bak              6149           Deleted
initrd.img-4.15.0-135-generic.new                 6152           Deleted
extundelete: Operation not permitted while restoring directory.
extundelete: Operation not permitted when trying to examine filesystem

root@server:~# ls /dev/dm-0
ls: cannot access '/dev/dm-0': No such file or directory
```

Comment: `ls: cannot access '/dev/dm-0': No such file or directory`: that is what I also see on my system. So not sure if you were really able to delete it in the first place. `/dev/` is also not physically located on a hard drive, and is created while the system boots. If your server can reboot, all might be OK.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to reboot, so hopefully nothing bad happened. I remounted that other directory.